# Spring boot application cannot run using cmd

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cmd, runtime-error

I try to run my compiled jar file using java -jar jarfile.jar but it returning following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:593)
```

Why this is happening. When i run in the spring tool suit it run perfectly. This happen only when i try to run my application using CMD windows

Comment: is it gradle or maven project?

Comment: Maven project @SayantanMandal

Comment: could you try below steps from project root folder:
1: maven clean install  2: java -jar /build/lib/your.jar

Comment: When i run using mvn it says  Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property @SayantanMandal

Comment: could you post your pom here? Might be some dependency missing.

Comment: How are you building the jar? And have you defined the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED This answer is correct.** 
This is the error i have done when configuration of my pom.xml in the api module of my project.

```
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.mobios.MainApplication</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Following line create error**

```
<mainClass>MainApplication</mainClass>
```

This define the main class of the application. But i have only mentioned the class name only. It must include the group id also. I think lot of people doing this kind of simple mistakes like me. As a spring boot beginner i think it is common. The above line must be like following.

```
<mainClass>com.mobios.MainApplication</mainClass>
```

Now working fine when building the jar and run it. But without group id i can run the project in eclipse or any other development tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this type of spring boot application class?

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


    @SpringBootApplication
    public class FApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(FApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

May be your application can not find java manifest on your jar file.

Comment: `import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
 }
}`    This is my main class. This application perfectly running in the Spring tool suit but when i create jar and run it using cmd this error occurred @flopcoder

Comment: Goto the application root folder. Then run mvn clean install. Then goto target folder where jar file is located and then run java - jar jarfile.jar

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and goto your  where pom.xml presents 
run `mvn clean install`
once you get the message **build successful**

goto **target** folder by `cd target`
then run the command **`java -jar <file-name>.jar`**

if you are still getting the error message while running then some spring config is wrong.

create new spring boot application from `https://start.spring.io/`

Comment: yah sometime the tool cannot clean and build the project. I have face to that error previously and after 12 hours continue research i solve that problem as you said. by using cmd `mvn clean install` it build the project successfully that field when i build using spring tool suit. If someone facing weird errors try build using cmd Follow the process mention by @TheSprinter